# Overriding object getter without defineProperty

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I've defined a property with a getter using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2FdefineProperty) and i'd like to be able to overwrite it without needing to use `defineProperty` to prevent any confusion for coworkers who are going to consume it but may not know it's not a a "normal" property. I've tried the `writeable` and `configurable` options to no avail.

```js
var fixture = {
  name: 'foo',
  color: 'green'
};

Object.defineProperty(fixture, 'email', {
  get: function () {
    return 'test+' + Date.now() + '@gmail.com';
  },
  configurable: true,
  writeable: true
});

console.log(fixture.email); // test+<date>@gmail.com
fixture.email = 'bob'; // consumer attempts to overwrite
console.log(fixture.email); // test+<date>@gmail.com T_T

// this _will_ modify the property
Object.defineProperty(fixture, 'email', {
  value: 'overwritten'
});
console.log(fixture.email);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've tried the writeable and configurable options to no avail.

`writable` is only available for data properties, i.e. the ones that have a `value` not getter and setter.

`configurable` is only to allow deletion and redefinition, not to make the property settable.

If you want `fixture.email = 'bob';` not to throw an error, you'll have to provide a `set` method on your attributes object. This method may now:

- ignore the new value
- store the new value, e.g. in a different property or a closure variable, so that the getter can yield it on subsequent accesses (@Icepickle has some examples of this in his answer)
- convert the accessor property back to a "normal" one

The last is probably the easiest and most rewarding choice:

```
var fixture = {
  name: 'foo',
  color: 'green'
};

Object.defineProperty(fixture, 'email', {
  get: function() {
    return 'test+' + Date.now() + '@gmail.com';
  },
  set: function(val) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'email', {
      value: val,
      writable: true
    });
  },
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true
});

console.log(fixture.email); // test+<date>@gmail.com
fixture.email = 'bob'; // consumer attempts to overwrite
console.log(fixture.email); // bob
```

Answer (score 1):

Though, I wouldn't use it personally, i guess you could go around the problem and only let it be set when the value is specific to your expectations, if it's not a correct value, throw an error of some sort?

The downside would of course be that once they see code where you put in the code just like that, they could also do it, but i guess they would be already less confused then ;) I would actually prefer the second option i presented in the bottom that simply offers an extra setEmail method that does the setting itself, or by internally by updating the props.email property inside the "DataContainer"

```js
var data = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar'
};

Object.defineProperty(data, 'email', {
  get: function() {
    if (typeof this._props === 'undefined') {
      this._props = {};
    }
    return this._props.email;
  },
  set: function(val) {
    if (!val || !val.private) {
      throw 'no access exception';
    }
    if (this.email === val) {
      return;
    }
    this._props.email = val.email;
  },
  configurable: false
});

console.log(data.email);
data.email = {
  private: 1,
  email: 'hey.you@somewhere.hi'
};
console.log(data.email);
try {
  data.email = 'not allowed to set';
} finally {
  console.log(data.email);
}
```

An other way might simply to build the logic into a class constructor, and add a potentail setter over a function (or internally over a variable)

```js
function DataContainer(options) {

  var createProp = function(obj, propertyName, propertyHolder, isReadOnly) {
      Object.defineProperty(obj, propertyName, {
        get: function() {
          return propertyHolder[propertyName];
        },
        set: function(val) {
          if (isReadOnly) {
            return;
          }
          propertyHolder[propertyName] = val;
        },
        configurable: false
      });
    
      if (isReadOnly) {
        obj['set' + propertyName[0].toUpperCase() + propertyName.substr(1)] = function(val) {
           //internal setter
          propertyHolder[propertyName] = val;
        };
      }
    },
    prop = {},
    fieldProp, fieldVal, ro;

  if (options && options.fields) {
    for (fieldProp in options.fields) {
      if (options.fields.hasOwnProperty(fieldProp)) {
        fieldVal = options.fields[fieldProp];
        ro = false;
        if (typeof fieldVal === 'object' && fieldVal.value) {
          ro = fieldVal.readOnly || false;
          prop[fieldProp] = fieldVal.value;
        } else {
          prop[fieldProp] = fieldVal;
        }
        createProp(this, fieldProp, prop, ro);
      }
    }
  }
}

var data = new DataContainer({
  fields: {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',
    email: {
      value: 'test@something.com',
      readOnly: true
    }
  }
});

console.log(data);

data.email = 'test@test.com';
console.log(data.email);
data.setEmail('test@test.com');
console.log(data.email);
```